# how to list available Components and parameters in react and redux?

Tags: reactjs, list, redux, directory

Im learning react and redux and the course i'm following doesnt use the last versions of react and redux.

I stumble on the error on a form where the model is not found. I guess it's because of a renaming in the new redux...

```
<Control.checkbox model=".agree"  name="agree" className="check-input"/>
```

So I'm wondering, is there a way to list all the Components and their parameters in react/javascript/redux? a bit like dir(object) in python to list its methodes and attributes.

I find the documentation quite bad so i would like to explore on my own

thank you

Comment: Use the course to understand the concept. Then, implement the course-project using the latest version.

Comment: that's what im doing but some component have slight changes in the parameters calls or in their names...i dont know where to look to get lists of them

Comment: You seem to be using the library `react-redux-form`. Best to mention this explicitly in your question. You're only mentioning react and redux as separate libraries, they don't offer ready-made components out of the box. Documentation is usually on github: https://github.com/davidkpiano/react-redux-form/blob/master/docs/api/Control.md#model-required - you can also look up older versions there. You can simply print objects with `console.log(obj)` to see their properties, or inspect them in the browsers devtools (sources debugger). But it's not annotated like in python.

Comment: A bit of meta-advice: if a library's documentation seems lacking to you, to the point of not being able to use it productively - ditch it! You should not have to dive into the source code and play detective for simple basic things the library promises. Also, if you're learning only react and redux, there is no need to throw form libraries into the mix. If you must use a form handling library, I would recommend `react-hook-form`. It's simple and fast and doesn't involve redux.